# I am trying to force a packery.js shuffle when fullpage.js callbacks onSlideLeave and afterSlideLoad

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, packery

I have been trying to trigger the packery animation of resorting the items similar to the page resize.  I want the packery items to re-sort when the fullpage slide are switched.  I am open to using a different method but I have started down the path of trying to use the fit method, triggered when fullpage.js callbacks "onSlideLeave" and "afterSlideload" happen.  My idea was to move one item from the left to the right of the entire grid to force the reshuffle animation.  I have created a reduced test case on codepen, [reduced test case](http://codepen.io/ideascomealive/pen/dGqwJV).

```
enter code here
```

I'm sure that I have missed something or I am heading down the wrong direction so any assistance would be great, thanks!  It may be important to mention I was using the jquery methods for packery.

Comment: I have an example here using toggleclass instead of the fit method. http://codepen.io/ideascomealive/pen/BjOEPv I see the element get its changes to positioning but I still can't trigger the reloading of the grid.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I didn't realize that I needed to pass the index of the array along with the fit method.  http://codepen.io/ideascomealive/pen/dGqwJV
Using the fullpage slide variables to set the index number. Thank you to Alvaro Trigo and David DeSandro for your amazing libraries!  I'm new to stack overflow so I don't know the protocol for when you figure out your question before an answer comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can answer my own question if I discover what I was doing wrong so I hope this isn't poor etiquette.  As I commented, I wasn't passing the array number to the fit method.  Once I passed that in everything worked as it should.  I was able to use existing variables from the fullpage.js library to supply the index number.  [fixed codepen](http://codepen.io/ideascomealive/pen/dGqwJV)

```
var move = $('.move');
$('.grid').packery( 'fit', move[slideIndex], 0, 0 );
```